# Is array write atomic in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, atomic

```
var a = new bool[]{true,false};
var b = new bool[4];
a=b;       //operation 1
a[1]=true; //operation 2
```

I know that there are some atmoic types defined in C# ,from where I can't find array.

1. Opration 1 is something like a pointer reassignment. Does it
   **guarantee** to be atmoic?
2. How about operation 2?

Comment: i've never seen any operations that is not atmoic

Comment: Yes for both. See the specification, speficially [Atomicity of variable references](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/variables.md#atomicity-of-variable-references).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operation 1 is atomic. Operation 2 is not. From [the spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029):

> ### 5.5 Atomicity of variable references
>
> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic.

Arrays are reference types. Variable `a` and `b` are references, and so Operation 1 is a reference assignment: a simple write to a reference variable, and so is included. Operation 2 *looks like* a simple write to a `bool`, which would also be included, but don't forget the index lookup in the array. The array write itself *is* atomic, but when you include the lookup (dereferencing `a[1]`) there are two separate operations involved.

Comment: can you show some code to demonstrate the bad result of not being atomic?

Comment: I actually believe 2 is indeed atomic. One subsection prior the spec defines variable references as being expressions that are "lvalues" and later uses the variable_reference identifier to define expressions that maybe used as ref parameters. Array elements are allowed as ref parameters suggesting they are variable references covered by this section.

Comment: @LeiYang I wouldn't trust myself to get it right... or rather, "wrong", depending on your point of view :). You only see the problem when you have two threads working on the same value, and getting code to demonstrate that is tricky.

Comment: @mikez The assignment itself is atomic, but that's a tough sell for the whole statement.

Comment: so do you think **not atomic** is about the same chance compared to **threading not safe**?

Comment: @LeiYang "not atomic" is _one reason_ something might not be thread safe, but not the only reason.

Comment: so is there any point talking about **atomic** without **threading**?

Comment: @LeiYang Sure, when things like exceptions happen or a Thread.Abort is done on you due to a AppDomain shutdown (frequently happens in a IIS enviorment) things that are atomic will complete, things that are not atomic may be interrupted half way though.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Did you mean that the second operation would be non-atomic as long as the index is not a constant and could be possibly access ed by other threads?or this "non-atomic" doesn't really depend on anything, it's just true for array indexing?

Comment: There is some confusion in the comments here. There are three operations: obtain the value of `a`, obtain the variable at `[1]` of that array, and assign `true` to that variable. Any operations on other threads may be observed to be interleaved with these operations, but who cares? If we're in that situation then the problem is not the atomicity of the operation; the problem is that `a` could be mutated on another thread before or after the write and therefore we have a race condition that the program must either eliminate or be robust to.

Answer (score -1):

maybe i am not right, but it seems to me that `a[1]=true;` operation is not atomic,
`=true` looks like atomic according to specs, but during overall(`a[1]=true;`) operation we need to get 1 element from array and then set it to the value of `true`

Comment: Please do not post answers on questions that already have an accepted, correct answer. This answer adds nothing that is not already in the accepted answer.